# How to structure data for current location

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

Need advice on how to structure data on firebase.
Essentially I have a social app that tracks users location. I also have a follower/following model which muddles things a bit further.

Essentially I am thinking of something like:

1. collection users:

   - userid
   - name
   - other user specific info user
2. collection following:

   - userid
   - [array of followingid]
3. collection followed:

   - userid
   - [array of followedid]
4. User locations

   - userID
   - location of user
   - last update

Do you think this is a good approach?

Also, how does GeoFire come into play here? Where should I use it?

Advice much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's going to be tough to answer this question accurately. Your use case is not outlined and it appears there's unneeded duplicated data. While that's not a bad thing, it can cause complications and create a need for excessive queries. Also, [Arrays Are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) so please avoid using them. It's good to plan but you may want to consider banging out some code and do a test run with a Firebase structure first to see if the flow is what you want.

Comment: Tks, I will go ahead with this and see how it performs. I will try and stay away from arrays but its hard at the moment to come up with a different solution.